# Read variable from tex file and use it as an argument?

Tags: input

I am trying to read a file named `language.tex`. It has the following content:

```
english
```

This is a minimal working example of my code (it does not work though) where I am trying to use the content of `language.tex` as an argument for the `babel` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[\input{language.tex}]{babel}

\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

The result: the pdf file is not generated even after waiting a few minutes on a local machine. Why is that?

Comment: You can put `\def\mylanguage{english}` into language.tex and use `\input{languge} \usepackage[\mylanguage]{babel}`.

Comment: I suspect `englixh` is being written and you are executing `\usepackage[]{babel}`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you! I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Be aware that TeX does not work like Python... A Pythonista too. ;-)

Comment: Haha, yes, I'd have to get used to that. Oooor use the `pythontex` package for some tasks. But for this, I suppose it does not make any sense to use or even if, it would probably be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I was able to solve my problem by using the following as the content of `language.tex`:

```
\def\mylanguage{english}
```

Now, all I had to do was slightly change my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\input{language.tex}
\usepackage[\mylanguage]{babel}

\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```